# How to remove link tag from image using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm parsing an HTML document using Nokogiri. The code contain several images like this:

```
 <a href="http://url_to_big_photo.jpg"><img alt="alternative-text" border="0" height="427" src="http://url_to_my_photo.jpg?" title="Image Title" width="640"></a>
```

I'm trying to save that image to my S3 storage, change the style and remove the link. All the images have the css tag ".post-body img".

So far, the closest I got is this:

```
@doc.css(".post-body img").each do |image|
    @new_photo = Photo.create!(
       #Params required to save and upload the photo to S3.
        ...
        ...
       )
     # The url of the photo upload to S3 is @new_photo.photo.url
    image['src']= @new_photo.photo.url
    image['class'] = "my-picture-class"
    image.parent['src] = '#'
    puts image.parent.content
    @doc.to_html
  end
```

This removes the link to the big photo but obviously it isn't a good solution.

I've tried to replace the parent using image.parent << image as suggested on http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/nokogiri-talk/2009-June/000333.html but doesn't do anything and image.parent = image returns "Could not reparent node (RuntimeError)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert that mailing list example over to apply to your situation, you have to remember that `node` is the node they are trying to get rid of, which in your case is `image.parent`.

So instead of `image.parent['src] = '#'` you should try:

```
link = image.parent
link.parent << image
link.remove
```

**Edit:**

Actually, the above code would probably move all the images to the bottom of whatever element contains the link, so try this instead:

```
link = image.parent
link.replace(image)
```

Comment: Thanks. That solution removes the link but it moves all the images to the bottom of the document, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: OK.  See my edit.  I haven't tried it myself, but that replace method is documented here:  http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html